# Equivalence relation generation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I couldn't prove the reflexivity property of $\sim$, the others I've proved trivially:

[image]

Anyone could help me?

Source: [Wikipedia (Generating equivalence relations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Generating_equivalence_relations)

Thanks

Comment: The relation $R=\emptyset\subset X\times X$ generates the diagonal
$\triangle:=\{(x,x)\mid x\in X\}$ as equivalence relation. If $X\neq\emptyset$
then $a\Delta a$ for some $a\in X$. This in spite of the fact that
$R$ contains no ordered pairs. So indeed something is wrong here. They should add to the condition: ..or if $a=b$.

Comment: @drhab I took from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Generating_equivalence_relations

Comment: Use $\: n=1 \;$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer yes, I've also tried this, why $(a,a)\in R$?

Comment: $(a,a)$ is not necessarily in $R$. $\:$ Fortunately, it does not need to be in $R$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer but in order to have $a\sim a$, we have to have $(a,a)\in R$

Comment: After a second look I think that Ricky is right. If $a=b$ then indeed
there is some $x_{1}\in X$ with $a=x_{1}=x_n=b$. Next to that we have
$\left(x_{i},x_{i+1}\right)\in R$ *vacuously* for $i\in\left\{ k\in\mathbb{N}\mid k\geq1\wedge k\leq0\right\} =\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\: n=1 \:$ and $\: x_1 = a \;$.

$a = x_1 = x_n$

Since there are no integers $i$ such that $\;\; 1 \: \leq \: i \: \leq \: n\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1 \;\;$, $\;\;$ 

the condition "$(x_i\hspace{-0.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}x_{i+1})\in R$ or $(x_{i+1}\hspace{-0.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}x_i)\in R$, $i = 1,...,n\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1$" [holds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

By the the previous sentence and the line before that, $\: a \sim a \;$.

Comment: it's true, thank you!